# Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Alert'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to use the Alert component from material-ui and I successfully installed @material-ui/core but still giving an error Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Alert'

package.json

'''

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

'''

Note.js file

'''

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import Alert from '@material-ui/core/Alert';
```

'''

Comment: Please share the relevant code (e.g. how do you import, what is your package.json etc)

Comment: please check now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Alert](https://v4.mui.com/components/alert/#alert) is associated with Lab package of material UI. So you need to install it.

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/lab

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```